# Want to know the difference between PHP & WAMP Server

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I want to download PHP, after Googling, I saw I could download the WAMP server.

What is the difference between PHP and the WAMP server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is JUST the PHP Interpreter. WAMPServer is a stack of software, including Apache2, PHP and MySQL for Windows. It'll automatically install all three programs for you, and get them set up so that you don't have to install them individually. WAMPServer **includes** PHP

Comment: hi thank you very much for the prompt response

Answer (score 2):

`PHP` is a programming language.

`WAMP` is a **set** of tools for development, which includes:

- Apache (web server)
- MySQL (open-source database)
- PHP (scripting language)

There are other similar **sets**. Take a look on [AppServ](http://www.appservnetwork.com/)

Comment: hi thank you very much for the prompt response

Answer (score 1):

WampServer is a package of software (including php) and other software that most servers supporting php have.

It includes:

- php
- mysql
- phpmyadmin
- apache
- xdebug
- sqlbuddy
- webgrind

Comment: So I can install Wampserver instead of installing PHP

Comment: @karthic Yes, and you will be able to do just as much as you can on an online host. Actually more... Since you have full access to your own computer.

Comment: hi thank you very much for the prompt response

other than w3schools is there any best website to learn PHP

Comment: @karthic There are plenty of tutorials on youtube to help you understand the syntax. Once you get the syntax down you will pretty much only need php.net for the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

WAMP is basically a bundle of a lot of different things. Though I am simplifying it a lot, think of WAMP as what lets you view the files at, say, `http://localhost/` (it uses [Apache](http://www.apache.org/) to do that). PHP is what actually goes through your files and finds those `<?php ?>` snippets of code. It then processes and feeds that PHP into HTML code that your browser understands to Apache. Apache then shows it to your web browser.

So it isn't really WAMP vs. PHP: PHP is part of WAMP. WAMP is a package to make your life easier by installing a bunch of different stuff for you.